# gulp-uglify won't preserve files order

Tags: javascript, gulp, minify, uglifyjs, gulp-uglify

When I use [gulp-uglify](https://github.com/terinjokes/gulp-uglify) to minify the Javascript files the order gets messed up.

Lets say I have this task working as expected:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var gp_concat = require('gulp-concat');

gulp.task('js', function() {
    gulp.src([
            './public/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
            './public/js/functions.js',
        ])
        .pipe(gp_concat('combined.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.js + '/dist'))
});
```

Adding the uglify line to it changes the order of the `jquery` and `functions` files and places `functions.js` above `jquery`.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var gp_concat = require('gulp-concat');

gulp.task('js', function() {
    gulp.src([
            './public/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
            './public/js/functions.js',
        ])
        .pipe(gp_concat('combined.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.js + '/dist'))
        .pipe(uglify({
            preserveComments: 'license'
        }))
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.js + '/dist'))
});
```

Any possible solution to it ? 
Of course, functions.js is just a plane Javascript file with funtions in it and are not wrapped in an IIFE.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Karol Klepacki's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39510979/5892036) is correct about using `hoist_funs`, but that's an option for the [UglifyJS compressor](http://lisperator.net/uglifyjs/compress). As such it needs to be provided within the `compress` option:

```
.pipe(uglify({
   preserveComments: 'license',
   compress: { hoist_funs: false }
}))
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! It has been vital for me to just add the line where it says: compress: { hoist_funs: false }

Answer (score 0):

Please try disabling functions hoisting:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var gp_concat = require('gulp-concat');

gulp.task('js', function() {
    gulp.src([
            './public/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
            './public/js/functions.js',
        ])
        .pipe(gp_concat('combined.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.js + '/dist'))
        .pipe(uglify({
            preserveComments: 'license',
            hoist_funs: false
        }))
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.js + '/dist'))
});
```

Comment: Nop. Same result.