# Gulp not concatenating js file in correct order

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-concat, gulp-order

I am concatenating and minifying js files using gulp. But files are not concatenating in the order it should be, like this is the order I want :

```
 var scriptFiles = [
  'assets/lib/js/angular.min.js',
  'assets/lib/js/angular-sanitize.min.js',
  'assets/lib/js/angular-route.min.js',
  'assets/lib/js/angular-ui-router.min.js',
  'assets/lib/js/angular-css.min.js',
  'assets/lib/js/angular-select.min.js',
  'assets/lib/js/duration.js',
  'assets/lib/js/ui-codemirror.min.js',
];
```

**The problem is, after concatenation ui-codemirror.min.js file goes to top of the compiled file, which breaks the javascript since angular.js is not initialized/loaded.**

To solve this problem I tried to use **"gulp-order"** package and wrote this gulp task:

```
gulp.task('lib-js', function() {
  return gulp.src(scriptFiles)
    .pipe(jshint())
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
    .pipe(order(scriptFiles, { base: './' }))
    .pipe(concat('vendor.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/compiled/js'))
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/compiled/js'))
});
```

I passed the same scriptFiles array to try to preserve the order. But it did not work.

Then I tried the **streamqueue** plugin, and change the task:

```
gulp.task('lib-js', function() {
  return streamqueue({ objectMode: true },
      gulp.src('assets/lib/js/angular.min.js'),
      gulp.src('assets/lib/js/angular-sanitize.min.js'),
      gulp.src('assets/lib/js/angular-route.min.js?v=20161018-1'),
      gulp.src('assets/lib/js/angular-ui-router.min.js'),
      gulp.src('assets/lib/js/angular-css.min.js'),
      gulp.src('assets/lib/js/angular-select.min.js'),
      gulp.src('assets/lib/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js'),
      gulp.src('assets/lib/js/material.min.js'),
      gulp.src('assets/lib/js/ocLazyLoad.min.js'),
      gulp.src('assets/lib/js/duration.js'),
      gulp.src('assets/lib/js/ui-codemirror.min.js')
    )
    .pipe(concat('vendor.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/compiled/js'))
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/compiled/js'))
});
```

This did not work either. I am unable to debug why this is happening. "order" and "streamqueue" plugin had not effect on the output. Any idea/solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gulp-uglify won't preserve files order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39510601/gulp-uglify-wont-preserve-files-order)

Comment: Try to eliminate everything apart from the `concat` step from your pipeline to make sure if it's not another plugin that is breaking the order.

Comment: Thanks @SvenSchoenung, it was happening because ui-codemirror function was hoisting due to uglify plugin. After adding `uglify({compress: { hoist_funs: false }}`, it worked. Thanks for the help @jannis